# django filter : can filter with tuple?

Tags: python, django, filter

Suppose, there is a list

```
strings = ['a','b','c']
```

And There are two model

```
class theModel:
   theString = models.charField()

Class superModel:
   hasClass = models.ForeignKey(theModel)
```

Is there any way to filter superModel by 'theString' with list?

for example this can be one way ( but is there any better way? without for loop )

```
tuple = []
for string in strings
   tuple.append ( theModel.objects.filter(theString = string) )

result = []
for theModel in tuple 
   result.append ( superModel.objects.filter(hasClass = theModel ) )

return result
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
theModel.objects.filter(theString__in=[1,4,7])
```